# Bitwise Operators in GAP

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, gap-system

Is one able to to use bitwise operators in the GAP programming language? For example, in Python one can do the following:

```
a = 60            # 60 = 0011 1100 
b = 13            # 13 = 0000 1101 
c = 0

c = a & b;        # 12 = 0000 1100
c = a | b;        # 61 = 0011 1101 
c = a ^ b;        # 49 = 0011 0001
c = ~a;           # -61 = 1100 0011
c = a << 2;       # 240 = 1111 0000
c = a >> 2;       # 15 = 0000 1111
```

I'd like to be able to do all of the above operations in GAP, but I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

Here is a link to the documentation: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap0.html

Comment: can you provide a link to the documentation?

Comment: is it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAP_(computer_algebra_system)? If yes then does it work with binary?

Comment: Yes that is the program in question. What do you mean "does it work with binary"?

Answer (score 1):

No, no such operations are directly available. Depending on what you actually want to do, you could of course "emulate" them in various ways, but that won't be quite as efficient. For example, you use boolean lists (which are internally stored as bitstrings), or vectors in a vector space over GF(2).